# Run-time error '424' when building VBA macro

Tags: vba, outlook

There are a bunch of questions about this here that have been answered but I have not been able to find anyone of them relevant to my situation. As I am new to VBA, I'm sure this is something simple that I am missing. I even ran through the steps here to ensure that I had access to the DAO (3.6 in my case):

http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/163475

Can somebody help me figure out what is going wrong with my VBA script below?

I am trying to trim a bunch of useless text from an email's subject line as it comes into my inbox. Note that the items with this subject will land in various sub-folders in my inbox in case that matters:

```
Sub ChangeSubject()

If Left(Item.subject, 31) = "Your Work Item Changed: " Then
Item.subject = Right(Item.subject, Len(Item.subject - 31))
End If

End Sub
```

Trying to run this from the VBA editor results in the Run-time error '424' message. Note that I am on Outlook 2013 on Windows.

Comment: Put `Option Explicit` as the first line of your code module, fix any errors, then see what is left.

Comment: The issue, that GSerg is also probably refering to, is that it doesn't know what the "Item" is.  You either need to pass the Item as a parameter to the sub or get it from somewhere.  You can find code that will make this an event whenever an email comes in (it's not currently) and then you can access the item using that code.

Comment: The text "Your Work Item Changed: " is 24 characters long so it's unclear why it is being compared to the first 31 characters of the subject

Comment: I realized that once I posted this. The actual text is different but I had to obfuscate it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Here's code to look at new items as they come in that I was referencing.

```
Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

      On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
      Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
      Dim emailSubject As String

      If TypeOf Item Is MailItem Then
          Set Msg = Item
          emailSubject = Msg.Subject
          'put additional code here
      End If

ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
End Sub
```

*Edited MailItem check per GSerg's comments.

Comment: `If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem"` -> `If TypeOf Item Is MailItem`

Comment: @GSerg I'm guessing the point of your code is speed optimization?

Comment: That, and also the compiler will tell you if you misspell the `MailItem`, and it will not give a false positive if someone passes a custom object called `MailItem` that is unrelated Outlook's `MailItem`. On a second thought, if your goal was to use late binding (otherwise why `As Object`?), then you should keep the `TypeName`.

Comment: Wasn't trying to use late binding.  I didn't know about the TypeOf statement and was curious as to what the benefits were.  I agree that it's better, so I updated the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: The ItemAdd event will not fire if multiple items are added simultaneously. Moreover, the original post contains the following text: *Note that the items with this subject will land in various sub-folders in my inbox in case that matters:*. So, you need to subscribe to each subfolder to get the event fired.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the thoughts. I will have to spend some time going through all of this to see if I can get it working :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what event is used for handling new mail items in Outlook. Anyway, I can suggest the following ways to get the job done:

1. Create a rule in Outlook which can run a VBA macro where you can change the subject line. There is no need to check each incoming mail item programmatically. The VBA macro will be called only if the incoming email satisfies your conditions. And the macro sub should look like the following one:

   ```
   public sub text(mail as MailItem)
     ' do whatever you need
   end sub
   ```

   Where the mail object represents the incoming email.
2. Handle the [NewMailEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863686.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event of the Application class which is fired when a new item is received in the Inbox. The NewMailEx event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the EntryIDCollection array to call the NameSpace.GetItemFromID method and process the item. Use this method with caution to minimize the impact on Outlook performance. However, depending on the setup on the client computer, after a new message arrives in the Inbox, processes like spam filtering and client rules that move the new message from the Inbox to another folder can occur asynchronously. You should not assume that after these events fire, you will always get a one-item increase in the number of items in the Inbox.

The ItemAdd can be used as well. But it is not fired if multiple items are added simultaneously (more than 16).